# List of Todos item whitespace

Tags: spacing, todonotes

How can you remove the whitespace between items in `\listoftodos` from the `todonotes` package?

Update:
MWE with correct spacing:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{todonotes}       %for todo's and in dutch
\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\todo[inline]{Test!}
\todo[inline]{Also test!}
\end{document}
```

MWE with extra whitespace:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
%\setlength{\parindent} {0pt}   %no indent between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[dutch]{todonotes}       %for todo's and in dutch
\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\todo[inline]{Test!}
\todo[inline]{Also test!}
\end{document}
```

Will have to take a look if the extra code is needed elsewhere.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Of course you fix what broke it when you reduce it. It seems an edit on paragraph side added whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the line

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

you are inserting an extra line spacing between paragraphs, and this behavior is inherited by the `\listoftodos`.

So, simply move that line after

```
\listoftodos
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
%\setlength{\parindent} {0pt}   %no indent between paragraphs
\usepackage[dutch]{todonotes}       %for todo's and in dutch

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\todo[inline]{Test!}
\todo[inline]{Also test!}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If the `\listoftodos` isn't the first thing in your document, you can adopt this way.
First save the value of the default `\parskip` and set it to `\baselineskip`

```
\newlength{\myparskip}
\setlength{\myparskip}{\parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

Then, when you need the default one, as in the `\listoftodos`, restore the default value

```
{\setlength{\parskip}{\myparskip}
\listoftodos}
```

Note the braces to keep the change local.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
%\setlength{\parindent} {0pt}   %no indent between paragraphs
\usepackage[dutch]{todonotes}       %for todo's and in dutch

\newlength{\myparskip}
\setlength{\myparskip}{\parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\parskip}{\myparskip}
\listoftodos}

\todo[inline]{Test!}
\todo[inline]{Also test!}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.